# array/other data structure to store data in 2 dimention

Tags: php, arrays, data-structures

Here First of all I fetched all tags from database. (tags are string like marketting,jobs etc).

`$POS` is array of POS(parts of speech words). For each words in this array, for given tag, I am calculating probability using writtten equation.

As it is appearing, two nested loops are there. To make decision, I need highest value from array `$prob` and tag belonging to that value.

Here in this code I will get all values in array `$prob` and from that I can get highest value, but how can I persist tag value too? is there any other data strcture in PHP to manage this short of scenario?

```
    $selectTag = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT tag from koove_tag");
    $prob = array();        
    $i=0;
    while ($row1 = @mysqli_fetch_array($selectTag))
    {
        foreach($POS as $p)
        {
            //Calculate total pos for given tag
            $selectPOS = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from koove_post where tag = '".$row1[tag]."'");
            while ($row2 = @mysqli_fetch_array($selectTag))
            {
                $totalPOSs.=$row2[pos].",";     
            }
            $totalPOS_count = str_word_count($totalPOSs);
            //calculate how many times particular 'pos' appears for given tag
            $selectPOS = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from koove_post where tag = '".$row1[tag]."'");
            while ($row3 = @mysqli_fetch_array($selectTag))
            {
                $POSs.=$row3[pos].",";      
            }
            $pos_Count = echo substr_count($string, $p);
            //calculate distinct POS in all POSs for all tags
            $selectPOS = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT pos from koove_post");
            while ($row4 = @mysqli_fetch_array($selectTag))
            {
                $POSs.=$row4[pos].",";      
            }
            $distinct_pos_Count = echo substr_count($string, $p);
            $prob[$i] = ($pos_Count + 1)/ ($totalPOS_count + $distinct_pos_Count);
            $i++;
        }               
    }
```

There are large numbers(thousands) of posts, if is there any better approach to faster the processing that also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly. Use the stdClass() object to hold the values that you need.  Then write method to sort them.  For example:

```
$prbo[$i] = new stdClass();
$prob[$i]->value =  ($pos_Count + 1)/ ($totalPOS_count + $distinct_pos_Count);
$prob[$i]->tag = $row1[tag];
```

After you build that array, then write a custom sort function.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use join query that will eliminate one of cycles.

2.You can get highest value with end(array) , or custom sort function.